# Docusign list of unsigned envelopes

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

When an admin user logs in to my app, I need a list of unsigned envelopes. What is the recommended way to get this list? I am using rest api v2.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify what falls under the category of 'unsigned'. Per below, you can run a query that returns any envelope that has been sent (unopened), and delivered (opened, but still not finished). This does not include envelopes that may have been declined by the signer for example, though you can modify your search query to include this status. Example query

```
GET: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<removed>/envelopes?from_date=9-15-2015+12:00:00+AM&status=sent,delivered
```

Sample documentation: 
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/